# Allow duplicate E-mail for magento customer Registration

Tags: magento-1.7, email

***when customer registered with already existing email id it allowed to create account .***
       for example existing email id:abc@gmail.com
        new customer register with the above email id it will create to account

```
 There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.'
```

Comment: This is a bad idea, plain and simple. What if a customer has 2 accounts and one wants to login in one in particular?

Comment: Putting on hold pending elaboration.

Comment: allow to register duplicate email to create account means customer register with existing email id allowed to create account

Comment: this task is done

Comment: 128  Phani Kumar  phanikumar.spk7@gmail.com  kummmmm  Consumer              Aug 5, 2014 5:00:59 AM           Yes  Edit
 127  S Kumar  phanikumar.spk7@gmail.com     Consumer              Aug 5, 2014 4:35:06 AM           Yes  Edit
 126  S Phani Kumar  phanikumar.spk7@gmail.com     Consumer              Aug 5, 2014 4:33:56 AM

Comment: the above are user are created in admin. frontend  login is also working for different users

Comment: @Pawankumar How did you achieved this? I need to do the same. I need to have multiple customers with the same email address. Thanks.

Comment: i removed foreign-key related for email in mysql.after that i removed required field for email field i made username as unique.based on firstname and laste name i am taking username if customer enter username that also fine if i am taking like that based on that i am creating users. Comming to login i am providing username or email login if enter email id with that email exist 3 or 4 i am showing next dropdown box in that he will select username and enter password it will login based on that

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately what you want is not possible or at least there's no easy way to achieve it. You see, e-mail address is not just an address, but it's also customers username.

While you could potentially write an extension that uses some other user attribute as a username / e-mail and thus allowing to have e-mail addresses that are not unique, many third party options expect them to be same and thus it's incredibly risky path to take.

Comment: well, that's not true, we're doing exact this for a client's shop. for login purposes we are using a custom login

Comment: when i override customer/resource/customer.php change some code.after that when register same mail id showing error msg cannot save customer

Comment: the error msg is Cannot save the customer.SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'pavan.kumar@exinent.com-1' for key 'UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID' like above error msg

Comment: please help for this module

Comment: This is not possible without extensive knowledge. Eail is a unique key and that is why you are receiving this error.

Comment: @bukart - pictures or it didn't happen. Care to add an answer that gives the necessary information?

Comment: You can allow to duplicate email by removing the unique key from "customer_entity" table "UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33525712/magento-customer-entity-table-remove-unique-key-in-table-properties/33526827#33526827

Answer (score -1):

you need to override the Magento model to perform this functionality.

It would be as simple as that.

@pawan I think you just want to show a message stating that their account is created rather than showing them that they are already registered user.

Comment: no,i want allow duplicate emails also to create account

Comment: Can you please explain what model to override? Because I think mbalparda is right, this is very hard to achieve.