# no warning message when using the same email to register account

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, register

I just found If I use the same email to create different account Magento would just reload the same page `www.domainName.com/index.php/customer/account/create/.` And there is no new account being created in the backend.

I found there should be something like a warning message saying `"There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, <a href="%s">click here</a> to get your password and access your account.'"`

[Allow duplicate E-mail for magento customer Registration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/allow-duplicate-e-mail-for-magento-customer-registration)

how do I fix this problem. thank you.

Comment: What you needs to fix allow duplicate email registration or shows error message?

Comment: to show error message

Comment: Which theme you used for store frontend?

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to multiple problems. Main issues that you need to check in this case is

- Check whether `<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>` is available in your `customer/form/register.phtml` file. If it is not there, then you need to add it.
- Check whether `AccountController.php` has any rewrite exists. If yes, then check the `createPost` action in that file and debug there untill you find the problem.

Generally this issue will be raised only when module rewrite occurs to the customer registration files.